# Hide navigation bar in android tablet with API level 19 and above

Tags: hide, fullscreen, android-softkeyboard, navigationbar, android-navigation-bar

My question is in android programming in android studio.
I can hide navigation bar but when dropdown spinner , it show again.
Besides that when i tap on EditText , revealing the softkeyboard  will cause the navigation bar to reappear.
how can solve it?
(I searched a lot but could not find the correct answer)

call this method in onCreate , onResume and onWindowFocusChanged

```
    private void hideNavigationBar() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```